# Why button appears only on the second attempt?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, addsubview

I'm trying to add a function that will show the close button in my custom alert view.
When I call it for the first time, only an empty area appears that does not contain a button (no color, no text and no pressing). When you call again - everything works as it should.

It does not depend on the parameter `animated`, in both cases it works the same.

My `dialogView` is a my custom `UIView`. I don't use `UIAlertController`

What could be the problem?

[initial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cM4RG.png) [after the first attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6HSn.png) [second attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD1HZ.png)
[GIF call func by click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rDRm.gif)

```
func showCloseButton(text: String, animated: Bool){
        let dialogViewHeight = self.dialogView.frame.height + 50 + 1

        let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: dialogViewHeight)
        button.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.dialogView.frame.width, height: 50)
        button.setTitle(text, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        let separatorLineView = UIView()
        separatorLineView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.dialogView.frame.height)
        separatorLineView.frame.size = CGSize(width: dialogView.frame.width, height: 1)
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.groupTableViewBackground
        dialogView.addSubview(separatorLineView)

        if animated {
            animateAdjustDialogView(height: dialogViewHeight){
                Logger.Log("completion did")
                self.dialogView.addSubview(button)
            }
        } else {

            Logger.Log("button.frame.origin = \(button.frame.origin)")
            Logger.Log("button.frame.size = \(button.frame.size)")
            Logger.Log("button.title = \(button.titleLabel)")

            self.dialogView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.dialogView.frame.width, height: dialogViewHeight)
            self.dialogView.addSubview(button)
        }
    }

private func animateAdjustDialogView(height: CGFloat, completion: (()->Void)?){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.dialogView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.dialogView.frame.width, height: height)
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (finished) in
            Logger.Log("finished = \(finished)")
            if finished {
                Logger.Log("completion run")
                completion?()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @RobertDresler I'm sorry, maybe I wrote it wrong. I added to the description - I do not use UIAlertController

Comment: You have added `self.dialogView.addSubview(button)` for both cases `if` and `else` as well. So better add button before or after `if-else`.

Comment: @AmirKhan But in the first case `if`, it is used not by default, but only in the completion block.

Comment: Ok got your point. Better add that button and `show/hide` it according to scenario. OR add button inside Main thread - `DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.dialogView.addSubview(button)
    }`

Comment: @AmirKhan Now I tried to add this code and execute it both before and after the `if-else` block, the result is the same.

Comment: Ok. Let me dig into it.

Comment: Can you add `animateAdjustDialogView` code snippet?

Comment: @AmirKhan I added this code. And also added a process animation (function call by click). But I think it should not be related to the animation and the function of adjusting the view, because it happens even in `else` block.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Button frame is causing the issue -**

```
button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: dialogViewHeight)
```

**Where**

```
let dialogViewHeight = self.dialogView.frame.height + 50 + 1
```

That means, `button` goes beyond `dialogView` `frame`.

**So replace**

```
button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: dialogViewHeight)
```

**With**

```
button.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: dialogViewHeight - 50) // Height of the Button.
```

Let me know if you are still having any issue.